# There a way in R to implement the apply function with dbWriteTable in DBI library to load multiple data frames into SQL at once

Tags: r, postgresql

I am new to SQL and R.  I previous did everything through Matlab and excel files.  I currently have a code in R to load an excel file into a `dataframe`.  However, I am interested in loading all excel files per directory.  Therefore, I have a code to save all `dataframes` in a list.  Moreover, I save all lists of these `dataframes` into another list.  Therefore I have a list of directories with lists of `dataframes` corresponding to read excel files.

My question:  Is there a way to implement the apply function with `dbWriteTable` to this list of lists so that it loads into my `postgreSQL` database all of these into their own tables.  The for loop approach seems very inefficient.

```
apply(dbWriteTable,conn=conn_R,name=list_of_names,list_of_list_of_dataframes)
```

Comment: *so that it loads into my postgreSQL database all of these into their own tables* ... is not a well-designed database. PostgreSQL (or any relational database) is NOT a spreadsheet system and should NOT be a data dump of Excel files. Avoid many tables with likely repetitive identifiers and relational redundancy. Understand the relationships in your data and migrate data to normalized tables.

Comment: Thank you for the insight!  Unfortunately,  I am working clinical pathology measures (70) for 13 timepoints for over 100 animals.  I was provided the raw excel files for all measures.  Considering your suggestion, I could try and combine them, but  I thought that was the point of SQL -- to make it easier to call items and compare each one for the point of understanding them. These excel files currently list all animals with all timepoints per measure;  There are 70 excel sheets.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: Combine the 70 Excel sheets into **one** object and import this object into database. From description, consider one-to-many relationship with *animals* table and *timepoints* table.

Comment: Fantastic suggestion, thank you!  I'm still learning to navigate this realm of bigger data-sets than I typically see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we have to feed table_name and df_name in every dbWriteTable iteration. `map2` from `purrr` can do this.

```
library(purrr)
map2(list_of_names, list_of_dataframes, function(x,y) dbWriteTable(conn_R, x, y))
```