# Splitting a Dataset into Arbitrary Sections

Tags: sql, r, iteration, data-manipulation, dbi

I have this data set:

```
var_1 = rnorm(1000,1000,1000)
var_2 = rnorm(1000,1000,1000)
var_3 = rnorm(1000,1000,1000)

sample_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)
```

I would like to split this data set into 10 different datasets (each containing 100 rows) and then upload them on to a server.

I know how to do this by hand:

```
sample_1 = sample_data[1:100,]
sample_2 = sample_data[101:200,]
sample_3 = sample_data[201:300,]

# etc.

library(DBI)

#establish connection (my_connection)

dbWriteTable(my_connection,  SQL("sample_1"), sample_1)
dbWriteTable(my_connection,  SQL("sample_2"), sample_2)
dbWriteTable(my_connection,  SQL("sample_3"), sample_3)

# etc
```

Is there a way to do this "quicker"?

I thought of a general way to do this - but I am not sure how to correctly write the code for this:

```
i = seq(1:1000, by = 100)
j = 1 - 99
{
sample_i = sample_data[ i:j,]

dbWriteTable(my_connection,  SQL("sample_i"), sample_i)
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164525/splitting-a-large-data-frame-into-smaller-segments

Comment: Thank you! I saw a similar command - but from here, how do you save each of these files individually (e.g. sample_1, sample_2, etc)? In the link you posted, the final output is a "list". Also, is it possible to bulk upload them at the same time?

Comment: Sure, you can iterate over the list calling `dbWriteTable()` on each element. There's an example of using `map2` from the `purrr` package over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604971/there-a-way-in-r-to-implement-the-apply-function-with-dbwritetable-in-dbi-librar

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering, why do you need both  "list_of_names" and "list_of_dataframes"? Couldn't you just use "lis_of_names"?  map2(list_of_names, list_of_dataframes, function(x,y) dbWriteTable(conn_R, x, y))

Comment: Sorry, not following. Your pseudo code here, though, seems logical. `map2` iterates over two inputs simultaneously. One input can be the list of data table names and the other can be the list of data frames (that is, the output of the your earlier split). With `split()` and `map` you should have what you need to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I put a more complete example together as an answer. Perhaps that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using the SQLite database engine. We'll start with your sample data set:

```
var_1 = rnorm(1000,1000,1000)
var_2 = rnorm(1000,1000,1000)
var_3 = rnorm(1000,1000,1000)

sample_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)
```

Now we'll break your large data frame into a list of 10 data frames using `split()`. The result will be stored in a list:

```
list_of_dfs <- split(
  sample_data, (seq(nrow(sample_data))-1) %/% 100
)
```

We'll create a vector with the names of the tables in the database. Here, I'm just making simple vector with the names `sample_1`, `sample_2`, etc.

```
table_names <- paste0("sample_", 1:10)
```

Now we're ready to write to the database. We'll make a connection and then iterate over the list of data frames and the vector of table names simultaneously, calling `dbWriteTable()` each time:

```
connection <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "test.db")
map2(
  table_names, 
  list_of_dfs, 
  function(x,y) dbWriteTable(connection, x, y)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was there any reason that you decided to use the RSQLite library?  Is it possible to upload the files using "dbWriteTable()" insteadof "dbConnect()"? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: I used RSQLite because it was the quickest way for me to demonstrate the flow of activities. You can use whatever interface is appropriate for your database. At least with RSQLite, it's necessary to establish a connection to the database (that's what `connection` is) and then use that handle in subsequent called to `dbWriteTable()` or other database functions.

Comment: dbWriteTable(my_connection,  map2(
  table_names, 
  list_of_dfs, 
  function(x,y) dbWriteTable(connection, x, y)) .... should this work? Thank you!

Comment: No. Follow the flow above. Construct a list of data frames with `split()` and a vector of table names. When you call `map2()` it will call `dbWriteTable()` for every item in the list and in the vector. In this example, that one call to `map2()` will result in 10 calls to `dbWriteTable()`.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand! This line just establishes the connection: connection <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "test.db") .... I don't have to run this line. I can just keep my pre-existing connection

Comment: So all I have to do is just run the following lines once all the mini tables have been created: map2(
  table_names, 
  list_of_dfs, 
  function(x,y) dbWriteTable(connection, x, y)
)

Comment: I think you have it! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! BTW this question that I posted is actually in reference to another problem I am currently facing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417489/tricking-an-sql-server-to-accept-a-file-from-r).I thought of this idea (that you showed me how to do ) as a diagnostic tool to attempt to solve this other problem. Once again, thank you so much!